# How do I calculate the Rolling Average for the difference of days between events on BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table of events that goes like this:

```
date                  event_category     event_planner

2019-09-22T00:00:00   soccer_night       Marcus
2019-09-25T00:00:00   comedy_night       John
2019-09-28T00:00:00   dance_party        John
2019-10-02T00:00:00   soccer_night       Marcus
```

The idea here is to get the rolling average of the difference between dates for every planner.
So far I have the distance in days for each planner separated by category with the following:
`DATE_DIFF(SAFE_CAST(date AS date),LAG(SAFE_CAST(date AS date)) OVER (PARTITION BY event_category, event_planner ORDER BY date), day) AS result`

What I expect is something like this:

```
date                  event_category     event_planner     rolling_avg

2019-09-22T00:00:00   soccer_night       Marcus            0
2019-09-25T00:00:00   comedy_night       John              0
2019-09-28T00:00:00   comedy_night       John              3
2019-10-02T00:00:00   soccer_night       Marcus            10
2019-10-10T00:00:00   comedy_night       John              7
```

Comment: where is the average in your example? please clarify

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant the average is to be calculated creating the rolling average from the distance of the days in 'date'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(day, diff), IFNULL(AVG(diff) OVER(PARTITION BY event_category, event_planner ORDER BY day), 0) rolling_avg
FROM (
  SELECT *, DATE_DIFF(day, LAG(day) OVER(PARTITION BY event_category, event_planner ORDER BY day), DAY) diff
  FROM (
    SELECT *, SAFE_CAST(date AS DATE) AS day 
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
  )
)
```

If to apply to sample data from your question

```
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-09-22T00:00:00' date, 'soccer_night' event_category, 'Marcus' event_planner UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-09-25T00:00:00', 'comedy_night', 'John' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-09-28T00:00:00', 'comedy_night', 'John' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-10-02T00:00:00', 'soccer_night', 'Marcus' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-10-10T00:00:00', 'comedy_night', 'John' 
)
```

result is

```
Row date                    event_category  event_planner   rolling_avg  
1   2019-09-22 00:00:00 UTC soccer_night    Marcus          0    
2   2019-09-25 00:00:00 UTC comedy_night    John            0    
3   2019-09-28 00:00:00 UTC comedy_night    John            3.0  
4   2019-10-02 00:00:00 UTC soccer_night    Marcus          10.0     
5   2019-10-10 00:00:00 UTC comedy_night    John            7.5
```

> How should I modify to use the average from the last three events of the same type by the same planner?

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(day, diff), 
  IFNULL(AVG(diff) OVER(PARTITION BY event_category, event_planner ORDER BY day ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW), 0) rolling_avg
FROM (
  SELECT *, DATE_DIFF(day, LAG(day) OVER(PARTITION BY event_category, event_planner ORDER BY day), DAY) diff
  FROM (
    SELECT *, SAFE_CAST(date AS DATE) AS day 
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
  )
)
```

Comment: This works great, there's one more thing though. How should I modify to use the average from the last three events of the same type by the same planner?

Comment: not sure if this was in your original question - anyway - see update

Answer (score 1):

You could compute the last date in a subquery using `lag()`, and then do a rolling average in the outer query:

```
select
    t.*,
    avg(date_diff(date, lag_date, day)) over(
        partition by event_category, event_planner order by date
    ) rolling_avg
from (
    select
        t.*
        lag(date) over(
            partition by event_category, event_planner order by date
        ) lag_date
    from mytable t
) t
```

Comment: This works great, but as a followup, how should I modify it to use the average between the last three events from the same planner?

Comment: @ClaudioDavi: something like `avg(date_diff(date, lag_date, day)) over(
        partition by event_category, event_planner order by date
        rows between 3 preceding and current row
    ) rolling_avg`

Answer (score 0):

For the average you can use:

```
(DATE_DIFF(MIN(SAFE_CAST(date AS date)) OVER (PARTITION BY event_category, event_planner),
           SAFE_CAST(date AS date),
           day
          ) / 
 NULLIF(COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY event_category, event_planner) - 1, 0)
) AS result
```